# Dask dataframe str.contains(regex=True) no faster than pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a pandas dataframe I want to regex search in:

```py
df[df['material'].str.contains(r'\baluminum\b', regex=True)]
```

I assumed this would be parallelizable with Dask, but it yields no performance improvement:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=8)
dask.config.set(scheduler=dask.multiprocessing.get)

# Pandas DF
%timeit df[df['material'].str.contains(r'\baluminum\b', regex=True)]
23.7 s ± 571 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Dask DF
%timeit ddf[ddf['material'].str.contains(r'\baluminum\b',regex=True)].compute()
25.6 s ± 1.25 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Why is that? Isn't this operation parallelizable?

Update: If I run this as part of a local distributed cluster using `client=Client()`, then it parallelizes. But it doesn't when I switch back to standalone mode. I've also tried setting `scheduler='processes'` but it behaves the same.

Comment: What is the shape of the inbound dataframe? Yiu have a fair bit of overhead with chunking and transferring the chunks to the subprocesses.

Comment: The shape is (1507789, 10)

Comment: did you make it working? tried same thing and it won't parallelize

Comment: No, the question remains open.

Answer (score 1):

By default dask dataframe uses the multi-threaded scheduler.  Regex computations probably don't release the GIL.  You might want to try the multi-processing scheduler instead.  Please see https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html

Comment: I am using the multiprocessing scheduler:
`dask.config.set(scheduler=dask.multiprocessing.get)`